# XAMARIN / ANDROID / XML - listview scrolling

Tags: android, xml, listview, xamarin

I want to disable the scrollbar for listview and enable it for **main scrollbar** activity. I add them with a simple adapter, here is the code and views:

Sorry for the indirect link, but i haven't got more then 10 reputation, and i can't add more than 2 links:
http://pastebin.com/Vufm45tG

A picture of the view:
http://pl.tinypic.com/r/k0hkq1/8

Comment: ***"This paste has been removed!"*** Post your code directly in your post here on stackoverflow! http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: possible duplicate of [XAMARIN / ANDROID - xml disable scrollbar for listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234303/xamarin-android-xml-disable-scrollbar-for-listview)